# What does comma expression in for loop means in Python?

Tags: python, loops, foreach

I met the following loop header example:

```
for _, p in data.iterrows():
```

What does it mean? What is underscore and what is comma?

**UPDATE**

iterrows is from here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: Underscore is an argument that has no name, a placeholder of sorts, so its declaring 2 args, _ and p.

Comment: And what goes to these args?

Comment: _ and p are given data.iterrows();, probably a tuple with the variables representing the returned data respectively

Comment: `data.iterrows()` would return a tuple containing two values [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], etc. The underscore would be the first (1, 3, 5) while the p would be the second (2, 4, 6). It would most likely only be used as a placeholder if the first values were not needed but the values in p are.